# Importing and saving big text data to MATLAB format

Tags: matlab, text, bigdata

I have big txt files (~25MB). It don't open properly in excel and doesn't work to try to import it.

Using the following comands I can read what there is inside... but I can not save it as a matlab file to use together with other data.

I'm trying:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt')
while~feof(fid)
tline = fgets(fid);
disp(tline);
end
```

I tried both `fgets()` and `fgetl()`. It reads the entire file. But doesn't store the information in workspace.

Comment: You are aware that fgets just reads one line? so tline will contain only the **last** line read (which very often is empty).

Comment: yes, I know... and that is the problem.... I'm not used with data handling using matlab... then, I asked for help! Thanks for your comment

Comment: It's ok to ask for help. I was just telling you in *your* snippet the content of the file is **not** stored in a variable. Therefore it will not be available.

Comment: What commands you suggest to use? is there any? fprintf?

Comment: The answer shows the way to do it. Maybe the command `textscan` is even faster. `C = textscan(fileID,'%s')` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

If the variable `tline` does not exist in the matlab workspace after you run that code, it's possible that you are running it in a function instead of a script. In addition, you need to save each line that you read in into an array of some kind so that it doesn't get overwritten by the next line you read in. i.e.

```
function foobar(foo,bar)
fid=fopen('file.txt')
n = 0;  
while~feof(fid) 
    tline=fgets(fid); 
    disp(tline);
    n = n + 1;
    data{n} = tline;
end
```

If you are calling it in a function, commenting out the function line will cause the variables to persist in the workspace.

Alternatively you could add a line of code to save the variables you need to a mat file and then open it later.

```
function foobar(foo,bar)
fid=fopen('file.txt')
n = 0;  
while~feof(fid) 
    tline=fgets(fid); 
    disp(tline);
    n = n + 1;
    data{n} = tline;
end
fclose(fid);
save('filename.mat','data');
```

and then from workspace run

```
load('filename.mat');
```

Note: Data may not need to be a cell. it depends on the type of data in the file

Comment: This only saves the last line of the file!

Comment: it didn't worked at all... it saves a matrix with the right size, but it is completely empty...

Comment: @FernandoLima, I tried creating a text file with some numbers and words in it and the code above worked for me. It stored each line of the file in a cell and made data a cell array. What are the contents of the file you are trying to read in?

Comment: the file contains only empty cells and strings cells (different words)... I'll try one more time this afternoon... I'll tell you the results later. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Here's Another way you might be able to store the data: add `strdata = []` before the while loop and `strdata = [strdata tline];` inside the while loop. That will concatenate the existing data in `strdata` with the `tline` data each time you read in new data.